# Given a second assignment for job interview. Big no or not a big deal?

Tags: interviewing

It seems to be a mini version of the first job interview assignment, for which I submitted a huge document and turned into a huge presentation, presenting it over an hour to the CMO. I was told this may be the last round, but am now given this assignment. Honestly, it hasn't bothered me. It seems like they want to get more details on one part of my first assignment to fill a gap about me as a candidate. And I'm excited about the company.

But it's important to me that I feel good if I do get offered the job and I know job interview assignments are a bit sticky. And I've been given two. And this one is asking for more details.

More than anything, by doing this assignment I feel like I'm communicating that I don't have another option which could hurt in future negotiation if I get there.

Are multiple interview assignments common or should I be concerned? Should I address with recruiter?

Edit- the fact that it's multiple assignments is my main concern, not the mere inclusion of an assignment.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [Interview programming assignment seems like free work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98215) or [Huge interview test seems like real (free) work for the company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/124554). Also related: [Is there a professional way to refuse a time-consuming programming task given as a test for a job?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/32808) The amount of work is more important than the number of assignments: consider spending 1 hour on each of 2 assignments versus spending 20 hours on 1 assignment.

Comment: This one is probably 25% of the work of the last one, but I spent days on the last assignment.

Comment: Do you still want that position?  If yes, you probably need to do the assignment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interview programming assignment seems like free work](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/98215/interview-programming-assignment-seems-like-free-work)

Comment: @John As everyone  is saying, it's free work.  Even if it isn't, just remember, the interview process is where the company puts it's very best foot forward.  If this is them at their best, imagine what it will be like working there

Answer (score 37, accepted):

> I submitted an 18 page document and turned into a 35 slide presentation, presenting it over an hour to the CMO

Unless you're going for a high level senior level executive type job, that's just ridiculous. If they've still got gaps to fill in "you as a candidate" after an interview and an hour long presentation on a specific task of their choosing (that took days!), then their interview process sucks.

Asking for yet another task after that is, in my view, rather unprofessional. Smells very much like free work.

If it were me, I'd thank them for their consideration but say you haven't the time available to complete any more work for this interview, so you'll have to pass. You can then likely spend your time much more efficiently applying elsewhere.

Comment: A working person would never have time for this amount of work.  They're fleecing the desperate and they know it, so here's another one.

Comment: At the very least, post a factual statement of what happened on GlassDoor, etc to inform others of what they may face if they apply to the company. No opinions & nothing derogatory, but the facts here should suffice.

Answer (score 12):

If they can’t evaluate your application on that huge amount of work then they are asking for work for free.

Ask to be paid and if they don't want to pay, say you are busy.

Depends how much you want this, but if that is their attitude be careful...

Comment: Asking to be paid for our time in interviews somehow does seem justified: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/145932/how-to-weed-out-fake-interview-invites

Answer (score 2):

You're working for free.

They've found a way to exploit your skills and experience for free without paying. I've had many interviews including various competency tests and technical interviews and I've never had an interview assignment before nor has anyone I've worked with nor has any of my friends or family.

Sorry this might sound harsh but there are people who don't feel bad about exploiting others for their own personal gain.

Answer (score -2):

With today's companies cross hiring applicants from other companies, one could say that more detail may infringe on another (ahem), application process somehow.  Back in the 80s, everyone had multiple signed agreements from every company they worked for (the silicon heyday).  It, perhaps will need a higher security clearance to complete, as will need more data, then what you are given now.  In this way, jf they are serious, they should give it to you, if not you have your answer.  Also copyright your work with agreement to transfer work if hired at x salary.  If not, sell it to someone else, as they were selling your skill for zero dollars.  Enough.  Either way, would be leery of a company that thinks so little of your time and ability.  They are turning their noses up at you, them being only company worth working for.

Answer (score -2):

I think all of you missed the real reason -

they have another interviewee in the process, and they want to keep you a while longer, in case that other person decides to decline their offer.